# Add Menu Block (module) Menu To Page tpl

Tags: theming, blocks

Hello i am trying to avoid using the block system with drupal. Im using panels and i dont like having to add the main content if i use any block in a region. anyhow.... i was hoping to add a menu block i have to my page.tpl

The block i want to add has this url to it when i edit it-
block/manage/menu_block/2/configure

The code im using to add another block is

```
    <?php
      $block = module_invoke('md_megamenu', 'block_view', '1');
      print $block['content'];
    ?>
```

Ive tried a few things with not much success. If i was to choose my best effort it would be-

```
   <?php
             $block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', '2');
          print $block['content'];
        ?>
```

this just shows 'array' though.

could anyone suggest anything i should try?

Thanks

Comment: So are you on Drupal 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're mixing the Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 api a little bit.

If you're on Drupal 7, you should print out your block like this:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

Note the '**print render**'. (You're missing the 'render' part if you're on Drupal 7.

The only things you need to change are to put '**menu_block**' for the 'module_name' and your **block's machine name** for 'block_delta'.

More info and examples are on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/26502

Does that work for you?

============ Edit ==============

On the other hand, if you're on Drupal 6, your call should look something like this:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block', 'view', 'block_delta');
print $block['content'];
?>
```

In this case, you're fine with the just 'print $block['content']', but your arguments are a little off.  From what you're saying though, it sounds like you're on Drupal 7, and are just returning the array without rendering it!!! :-)

Comment: ah thanks Boriana i was away off working on another of my drupal problems there. Let me read up....ah wait a sec...before i do this ive just realised that ive resorted to using a sidebar in my theme and im just putting the blocks in there. That said my md_megamenu block will need the D7 way of doing things you suggest. Let me go try that....yip thats great Boriana. Im glad i found out that im doing things the wrong way. Much appreciated thanks